# Why does this sentence start with the dative article "Dem"?

Tags: grammatical-case, definite-article

Reading the book "Kielings kleine Waldschule" the paragraph starts with this sentence

"Dem Interesse an der Natur einerseits, das ich zum Beispiel bei meinen Facebook-Followern feststelle, steht andererseits eine gewisse Entfremdung von der Natur gegenüber." Seite 18.

Why does this sentence start with the dative article "Dem" and not the nominative  case "Das" ?

Comment: It's a long sentence. Have you tried to identify the subject?

Comment: Think the fact that the sentence included  "einerseits" und "andererseits"  had confused me.  So I took the "Dem Interesse an der Natur einerseits" as subject.  I had wondered whether "Interesse an"  had governed the dative in some way.  I had always considered the natural order as einerseits und andererseits.

Comment: That's understandable. The einerseits/andererseits keeps us from rearranging the sentence in SVO order, which is a bit unusual.

Comment: "Interesse an" only governs the dative "der Natur". The sentence can be simplified by dropping the words "einerseits"/"andererseist", which makes it perhaps easier to parse; adding these two words merely gives (even more) emphasis on the opposites expressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Dem Interesse an der Natur ... steht ... eine gewisse Entfremdung von der Natur gegenüber.

That's what it is.

You could rearrange the sentence to: *eine gewisse Entfremdung von der Natur steht dem Interesse an der Natur gegenüber*

and if you compare this difficult sentence to an easier one like:

> Plötzlich stand er seiner Traumfrau gegenüber.

you'll see, that *gegenüberstehen* forms something like

> [Nominative] steht [dative] gegenüber.

Since German is flexible in word order, you need to figure out, what is subject and what is object. Subject is always in nominative.

> eine gewisse Entfremdung von der Natur

seems to be the subject here. So the other part is in dative case since *gegenüberstehen* is asking for an object in dative case.

Answer (score 2):

<gegenüber> + Dativ   Right?
The main subject in this long sentence is "eine gewisse Entfremdung von der Natur".
I rearrange below a typical S-V-O flow:
eine gewisse Entfremdung von der Natur
steht
andererseits gegenüber
dem Interesse an der Natur einerseits,
das ich zum Beispiel bei meinen Facebook-Followern feststelle.

Comment: Totally agree with the gist of the answer. Though strictly speaking, this is not a case of [gegenüber (preposition)](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/gegenueber_Praeposition) + Dativ, but rather of [gegenüberstehen (verb)](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/gegenueberstehen) + Dativ.